# Simulation of the direct piezoelectric effect using FEM

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, finite-element-method, partial-differential-equations

I have to simulate the direct piezoelectric effect, i.e. the generation of electrical charge under an applied mechanical strain using FEM with FEniCS. My geometry is a freestanding quadratic prism (a pillar). I've managed to simulate the bending of the beam and got some results regarding the stress and displacement that look quite nice. But I'm stuck on combining the linear elasticity with the electrostatics.

I have the following governing equations:

- Linear elasticity: $-\nabla\sigma = f = 0$
- Gauss' law: $\nabla D = \rho = 0$

And the constitutive equations of piezoelectricity:

$\begin{cases}\sigma = c\epsilon - e E \\ D = e\epsilon +\kappa E\end{cases}$

where $\sigma$ is the stress, $\epsilon$ is the strain, $f$ are the body forces, $c$ are elastic constants, $e$ are some piezoelastic constants, $\kappa$ are dielectric constants, $E$ is the electric field, and $D$ is the electric displacement.

I apply the bending force at one face by a traction $T=\sigma * n$, where $n$ is the normal of the face. My problem is, that I don't know how to properly "plug the governing equations together". I know that this somehow must happen by using the constitutive equations, but I don't know how exactly, because I'm not familiar with piezoelectricity and hence unsure about $c, e$ and e.g. a piezoelectric matrix $d$ which also is used in some literature. In some papers those matrices are huge and their dimensions don't fit the multiplication stated in the first constitutive equation (e.g. $c\in\mathbb{R}^{6\times 6}$ but $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$).

I appreciate any help and explanations, especially in deriving the variational formulation. Thank you.